# Extracting adjacent words in a string to help improve accuracy of named entity recognizer

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am working on building on Stanford NER to improve its accuracy. The idea is to identify POS tags and then collect all NNPs from a sentence and then iterate over each NNP and look at its adjacent words in the sentence. If there are syntactic cues present around the word like "CEO of" or "xyz said" then we know the first NNP is likely to be the name of an organization and the second one is a person. I'm trying to build rules on top of the parser to identify those labels that don't by the NER tagger.

So far I have been able to extract the NNPs but extracting adjacent words is something I'm having difficulty in. there isn't much info out there to do this in Java or Stanford NER..there is some stuff that works with Leucen like the NGramExtractor

How do I do this windowing in text? Thanks for any help. Pseudo code or instructions would also do.

Answer (score 0):

I should give the requisite warning about using these sorts of rules to second-guess a statistical model, namely that this sort of thing often backfires. The current CRF model has features that should capture these sorts of patterns, and if it's not capturing them then there's a decent chance that either (1) the pattern doesn't appear often, or (2) there are counter-examples to the pattern that you're not thinking of.

That said, you fairly easily create a [TokensRegex](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokensregex.html) extractor to label these sorts of patterns. This is actually how SUTime -- CoreNLP's temporal parser -- is implemented.